# accessing a file in the hierarchy- not working

Tags: php

How can I go out of the currect directory and access the test.php file?

I have tried the following:

```
realpath(__dir__.'../test.php');

realpath(__dir__.'./test.php');
```

But it does not work!

Also could you please let me know what is the difference between ./ and ../   ?

UPDATED:
The following lines give the following results:

```
   echo(__dir__.'\tests.php');
   echo "<br/>";
   echo(__dir__.'..\tests.php');
   echo "<br/>";
   echo(realpath(__dir__.'..\tests.php'));
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "hi";
   die();

Result:
C:\xampp\htdocs\proj1\includes\tests.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\proj1\includes..\tests.php

hi
```

So whay the third one is empty?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ad another directory separator and perhaps move the desired path . For instance, it's good practice to use the constant:

```
realpath(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test.php");
```

Edit:

`.` stands for "current directory" (has no practical effect in this case)

`..` stands for "parent directory" and goes up one level.

Comment: You solved my problem! I have updated my questions! Do you have any idea why my third command's result is empty?

Comment: Oh I see! I understood it!

Comment: now    echo(realpath(__dir__.'\..\tests.php')); works as well! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One dot (.) means 'current directory', and two dots (..) means 'parent directory'.

Keep in mind that `__DIR__` will be the directory that the currently running php file is in. Check with an 'echo `__DIR__`' first to make sure it's running from the directory you think it is.

Comment: Could you please review my questions one more time! I have updated it! Thanks :)